# How to map a new type with the keys of the value types of another type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, nested-generics

I'm trying to make a type from the type-values of another type but I get these weird edge cases....

[Here's a link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgQSgXigbwLABQhUUAdgPYAmEAoqQG4BcUA5GClS1AD6sDOwAIYBzCF14tq9FgBpiUQWDB0mrBOQDGghONYBHQbpYI49MXIIkIAW0GJmAlHFLCLJPteBgAEuQEPgJxdCAF8AbkJCUEhYRGQUACEsXHkNcnUUZhYUCEojYRyIUiMAIwQAV3N5EpRBUkosxTAEMR5WazgNDj5yADNgIz4QARsAdgA2FlDIgmjoAGkIEAA1bT40PgAVcAgAHgBhJ3i4QRkoeagIAA9ker4oAGslvqhDuGPBAD5kt4%20AbXmAF1LjcipR7o5nMIoAB%20KAABUEKGAJwQuwAShA0ihKAcjqgTgDAWdIS5Pt9mKQIGYUBEiLMdlAAMrkawQJkaAAWNkEePeBK%20yXw9JIABJenFUDDmE8QC9fgK3FBRdReoJykhpQpSCBQlAAGTnJarBDrLY7PkfM6y%20X4pxfGZpUgCKDWEDwJCoDnc2zMFls7083Ye%20Job7YYViiWezKsJoqWTydhUZiBSpKgQiCDMNWmiChOmEJ0u8jAbkoENerk8v2s9nV2zByWJcMpSzK6PxLI1Op5DPDZDWCZZMvQEoQASJ9tNFoj7mXQR8OATgZKjpdPx9YBz6AAd3IKEnoSAA)

What I'm trying to do:

Let's say I have a filter criteria where I want to say: "If I am filtering by value `X`, when the value is `Y`, set it to `true`, when the value is `Z`, set it to `false`":

```js
type KeyValsAsType<
    Criteria, 
    K extends keyof Criteria
> = Criteria[K] extends string ? (
    Partial<Record<Criteria[K], string>>
) : never;
```

This would allow me to deduce that, given the following type:

```js
type FilterA = {

  nodeEnv: 'prod' | 'stage' | 'dev',
}
```

I should be able to create a new type:

```js
type MyFilter = KeyValsAsType<FilterA, keyof FilterA>;
```

Which should mean that the following is a valid type:

```js
const X: MyFilter = {
    prod: true,
    stage: false,
    dev: false
}
```

If I were to add another key, it would populate those values as well, which is acceptable, however, if I were to add a `{ key: string }`, the `extends` type check jumps to the `never` clause

```js
type FilterA = {

  nodeEnv: 'prod' | 'stage' | 'dev', // populates if its by itself
  appEnv: 'local' | 'qa' | 'live', // also populates these values,
  email: string, // destroys the generic logic
}
```

Any ideas on how I can filter out keys that are non-specific? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: What's going on with the `string`-vs-`boolean` situation here?  Why would you be able to assign `true` or `false` to something that apparently needs to be a `string`?  If that's not related to the question, could you remove that so that your code is a [mre]?

Comment: Like, my suggestion looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NabZnm) but I don't think we want to be paying attention to `true`/`false` vs `"the best"` or whatever.  Let me know how to proceed.